# Possible to operate on all members of a homogeneous struct/tuple in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust, tuples

I have a vector with an `add` operator:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct float2(f64, f64);

impl Add for float2 {
    type Output = float2;

    fn add(self, _rhs: float2) -> float2 {
        float2(self.0 + _rhs.0,
               self.1 + _rhs.1)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write this in such a way that it would work for a 3D or 4D vector too?

e.g.: `struct float2(f64, f64, f64);`

I managed to add an `Index` operator, and a `len` method that returns a static value for each type, but this feels a bit cumbersome. I didn't check the assembly, but its possible all index accesses are checked, which seems unnecessary for such a low level operation.

I could also pack the struct and use direct unsafe memory access, but this also doesn't seem very optimal.

Is there a more convenient way to write expressions that handle all elements of the struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. What is possible is writing code that will write the code needed. This is known as *metaprogramming*. In Rust, there are two main avenues for metaprogramming: build scripts and macros. Compiler plugins also exist, but are much more complicated.

The Rust standard library uses macros to implement traits for arrays and tuples from 0 to 32, so it's certainly an accepted pattern. You should start by writing out a few cases to see how each iteration differs, then extract a macro from that.

Further reading:

- [Macros in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/macros.html)
- [*The Little Book of Rust Macros*](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/README.html)